# Получение и вставка значения элемента с использованием делегирования

Tags: javascript, html

Написал следующий код для получения значения из input и вставки этого значения в label и в обратном порядке. Но почему то происходит сбрасывание значения введенное в input и тем самым значение не сохраняется, в чем ошибка?

```js
function change(e) {

  if (e.target.tagName == 'TD') {
    if (activeEl) {
      activeEl.classList.remove('edit');
    }

    activeEl = e.target;
    var label = activeEl.querySelector('.column-label');
    var input = activeEl.querySelector('.column-input');

    if (activeEl.classList.contains('edit')) {
      label.textContent = input.value;
    } else {
      input.value = label.textContent;
    }

    activeEl.classList.add('edit');
  }
}

var table = document.getElementById('table');
var activeEl;

document.getElementById('table').addEventListener('click', change);
```

```css
table {
  margin: 40px auto;
  // border-spacing: 40px;
  border-collapse: collapse;

  
}

td {
    padding: 40px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

input {
  display: none;
}

.edit input {
  display: block;
}

.edit label {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
    <tr>
      <td class="table-column">
        <label class="column-label">1</label><input type="text" class="column-input">
      </td>
      <td class="table-column">
        <label class="column-label">2</label><input type="text" class="column-input">
      </td>
      <td class="table-column">
        <label class="column-label">3</label><input type="text" class="column-input">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="table-column">
        <label class="column-label">1</label><input type="text" class="column-input">
      </td>
      <td class="table-column">
        <label class="column-label">2</label><input type="text" class="column-input">
      </td>
      <td class="table-column">
        <label class="column-label">3</label><input type="text" class="column-input">
      </td>
    </tr>  
    <tr>
      <td class="table-column">
        <label class="column-label">1</label><input type="text" class="column-input">
      </td>
      <td class="table-column">
        <label class="column-label">2</label><input type="text" class="column-input">
      </td>
      <td class="table-column">
        <label class="column-label">3</label><input type="text" class="column-input">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В логике.

```js
var table = document.getElementById('table');
var activeEl;

function change(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName == 'TD') {
    if (activeEl) {
      activeEl.classList.remove('edit');
      var label = activeEl.querySelector('.column-label');
      var input = activeEl.querySelector('.column-input');
      label.textContent = input.value;
    }

    activeEl = e.target;
    var label = activeEl.querySelector('.column-label');
    var input = activeEl.querySelector('.column-input');
    input.value = label.textContent;
    activeEl.classList.add('edit');
  }
}


document.getElementById('table').addEventListener('click', change);
```

```css
table {
  margin: 40px auto;
  // border-spacing: 40px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
    padding: 40px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

input {
  display: none;
}

.edit input {
  display: block;
}

.edit label {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
    <tr>
      <td class="table-column">
        <label class="column-label">1</label><input type="text" class="column-input">
      </td>
      <td class="table-column">
        <label class="column-label">2</label><input type="text" class="column-input">
      </td>
      <td class="table-column">
        <label class="column-label">3</label><input type="text" class="column-input">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="table-column">
        <label class="column-label">1</label><input type="text" class="column-input">
      </td>
      <td class="table-column">
        <label class="column-label">2</label><input type="text" class="column-input">
      </td>
      <td class="table-column">
        <label class="column-label">3</label><input type="text" class="column-input">
      </td>
    </tr>  
    <tr>
      <td class="table-column">
        <label class="column-label">1</label><input type="text" class="column-input">
      </td>
      <td class="table-column">
        <label class="column-label">2</label><input type="text" class="column-input">
      </td>
      <td class="table-column">
        <label class="column-label">3</label><input type="text" class="column-input">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```